# FFmpeg (Webassembly) as Demuxer

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video-processing, webassembly

I am currently try to extend the following example:

https://chcunningham-samples.netlify.app/ffmpeg-wasm-demuxer/wasm_demuxer_demo.html

I would like to use FFmpeg to demux videocontainers with an audio- and videostream. But unfortunatly I am running into some problems:

Demuxing a file with only a audiostream works fine but as soon as I try to demux a file which includes a videostream I run into some errors:

First I get the following Warnings:

- parser not found for codec h264, packets or times may be invalid.
  -Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720 (0x0), 0/1, 2322 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
- Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
- Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, 69 kb/s): unspecified sample format
- Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options

When I then try to read a frame with the av_read_frame method I get the following error:

ffmpeg error str: Invalid data found when processing input

Do I have to extend the build process of the example to also allow to demux videostreams? Especially the h264 codec or what is causing the error?

Thanks in advance! :)

I already checked if my file is corrupted but that is not the case. I also tried to implement the h264 parser with the following cli parameter "-enable-parser=h264" unfortunatly nothing changed.

If you want to have more information about the file I try to demux, here you are:

```
General
Complete name: test.mp4
Format: MPEG-4
Format profile: Base Media
Codec ID: isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size: 17.5 MiB
Duration: 1 min 1 s
Overall bit rate: 2 400 kb/s
Frame rate: 30.000 FPS
Writing application: Lavf59.17.101

Video
ID: 1
Format: AVC
Format/Info: Advanced Video Codec
Format profile: High@L3.1
Format settings: CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC: Yes
Format settings, Reference frames: 4 frames
Codec ID: avc1
Codec ID/Info: Advanced Video Coding
Duration: 1 min 1 s
Bit rate: 2 322 kb/s
Width: 1 280 pixels
Height: 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio: 16:9
Frame rate mode: Constant
Frame rate: 30.000 FPS
Color space: YUV
Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0
Bit depth: 8 bits
Scan type: Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame): 0.084
Stream size: 16.9 MiB (97%)
Writing library: x264 core 163 r3060M 5db6aa6
Encoding settings: cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=18 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box: avcC

Audio
ID: 2
Format: AAC LC
Format/Info: Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID: 2 / 40 / mp4a-40-2
Duration: 1 min 1 s
Source duration: 1 min 1 s
Bit rate mode: Constant
Bit rate: 69.8 kb/s
Channel(s): 1 channel
Channel layout: M
Sampling rate: 48.0 kHz
Frame rate: 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode: Lossy
Stream size: 521 KiB (3%)
Source stream size: 521 KiB (3%)
Default: Yes
Alternate group: 1
```

Comment: _"...As soon as I try to demux **a file** which includes a video stream, I run into some errors"_ In all that text you wrote to explain the problem, **What** do you think is the **missing piece** to answer your question? A testable file might help us to answer you faster. **Why** is H264 involved in this (_ie:_ is that actually your file's codec)? **How** did you try to decode the H264 file (or maybe it's an MP4 file)? **PS:** Open your file at [MediaInfo online](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline) and let us know the format & codec... Show how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hey, first o fall thank you for looking at my problem. It doesnt depend on the file if the demuxing process works or not -  as soon as a file includes a videostream, the demuxing process isnt working anymore. But I updated the issue anyway with the information of an example file.

I think the missing piece is during the building process / Configurationen of FFmpeg. I never try to decode the file. I just want to demux the file in separate encoded chunks.

Comment: Knowing the setup of error-causing input file helps us to eliminate certain issues (compatibility etc). **(1)** What happens if you add your build options as `--enable-demuxer=mov --enable-libx264` before building FFmpeg? **(2)** Did you notice the demo's "Play" button at top of page is for audio playback only? I think that tutorial is about extracting audio from MP4, so you need to find one about building/compiling for handling the video codec too. **(3)** I use commandline FFmpeg for producing files, afterwards it's JS code that handles the bytes Array (for muxing, slicing, trimming, etc)

Comment: PS: I meant... Is using Javascript an option for this demuxing? It might be faster than using someone else's erroring code. Also... _"I never try to decode the file."_ yes but the data inside is still H264 so it must be processed by an H264 parser/decoder (knows what the header means, where to cut, etc)... **Fastest Solution**: Use different build options because that's the [wrong tutorial](https://chcunningham-samples.netlify.app/ffmpeg-wasm-demuxer/wasm_demuxer_demo.html) for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @VC.One I built FFmpeg in WebAssembly now with all libraries to see if the bug really lies in the building process. And yes, it did. Now I no longer get the error that the parser is missing. However, I still have a problem: 

When I demux a file with just a video stream (no audio stream), the whole process works. However, as soon as I demux a file with a video & audio stream, I still get the following error: 

- Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 2322 kb/s): unspecified pixel format

Comment: PS:

I increased the probesize and analyzeduration, but the error persists. Could you tell me what is causing the error?

The video & audio stream is the same as described above. I just separated the video stream into a separate container using FFmpeg.

Comment: Do you have a WASM file? You should look into tutorials on how to load it in the browser, then run FFmpeg with actual options (like how it's done on the command line). For example look at `const args =` on [this article](https://jeromewu.github.io/build-ffmpeg-webassembly-version-part-4-v0.2/). Now if you look at the tutorial you're following, it claims that [ffmpeg_demuxer.js](https://chcunningham-samples.netlify.app/ffmpeg-wasm-demuxer/ffmpeg_demuxer.js) is the main file for demuxing, but then search a variable called `decoderconfig` which doesn't have any input/output options.

Comment: Not sure how you're going to give your FFmpeg any command options if you keep following the directions in that tutorial. It doesn't seem flexible. Also not sure if `import {PullDemuxerBase, AUDIO_STREAM_TYPE}` should be supported by another `import {PullDemuxerBase, VIDEO_STREAM_TYPE}` or not, to handle video... so final solution: Either (A) follow a different tutorial on how to load your wasm and then move on to giving it startup options (what to with input/output) or (B) Just learn to do the demuxing in Javascript (load file into an Array, then slice sections that are a video or audio frame)